# Complex Update then Insert in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have spent many hours searching for a solution to my current problem, but with no luck.

I have 4 tables:

-**quest**

```
ACC_ID  key        value
10000   LOGIN      1
10000   LOGINCNT   3
10000   LOGINTMR   8465
10002   LOGIN      0
10002   LOGINCNT   2
10002   LOGINTMR   82415
10003   LOGIN      1
10003   LOGINCNT   1
10003   LOGINTMR   3650
```

-**characters**

```
*C_ID  ACC_ID  Online
100    10000   1
101    10000   0
102    10001   0
103    10000   0
104    10002   1
105    10003   1
106    10002   0
107    10000   0
108    10003   0
```

-**mail**

```
*M_ID  C_ID  Title    Message
1      100   Event    Free Gift
2      100   Event    Free Gift
3      104   Event    Free Gift
4      105   Event    Free Gift
```

-**mail_item**

```
*ID  M_ID  Item_ID  Amnt
1    1     3521     1
2    1     3522     1
3    3     3521     1
4    3     3522     1
5    2     1638     8
6    4     3521     1
7    4     3522     1
```

Note: column with * is unique to that table

what I want to do is `UPDATE` each *value* on **quest** table depending on these criteria..:

- if *key* is LOGIN and that ACC_ID is online on **characters** then *value* = 1 else if not online then *value* = 0.
- if *key* is LOGINTMR and that ACC_ID is online on **characters** then *value* = (UNIX Epoch time) else if not online then *value* = 0.
- if ever the first criteria's *value* is 1 then Insert New Row in **mail** and **mail_item** getting the *C_ID* from **character** which is online.

Notice that there are many rows on **character** with *ACC_ID* 10000 but only 1 row is online. Other *ACC_ID* might have no online character at all. So if a query is made on **characters**, it should return the row with *online*=1 or the last result if *online*=0.

Because of the complexity of this, it made my head spin in confusion. I hope someone could help.

Comment: Where do the columns in `mail_item` come from?

Comment: Why 100 is having two entries in mail table?

Comment: @Barmar - mail_item came from the attached item on mail..

Comment: @Valli - because a character can have many mails..

Comment: @KaryuuOuji I mean where do the values of `M_ID`, `Item_ID` and `amnt` come from when inserting in that table?

Comment: M_ID from mail table, Item_ID and amnt is supplied through code..@Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE quest AS q
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT acc_id, MAX(online) AS online
    FROM characters
    GROUP BY acc_id) AS c
ON q.acc_id = c.acc_id
SET q.value =
    CASE q.key
        WHEN 'LOGIN' THEN IFNULL(c.online, 0)
        WHEN 'LOGINMTR' THEN IF(IFNULL(c.online, 0), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)
        ELSE q.value
    END
```

And the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO mail (c_id, title, message)
SELECT c.c_id, 'Event', 'Free Gift'
FROM characters AS c
JOIN quest AS q ON c.acc_id = q.acc_id
WHERE q.key = 'LOGIN'
AND c.online = 1
```

I don't understand what should be inserted into `mail_item`.

Comment: is it possible to make it 1 query? so that if an account is online it will insert a mail..

Comment: No, it's not possible to do an update and insert in a single query.

Comment: Use a transaction to ensure consistency between them.

Comment: I only need to run this query once every day.. and will only check if an account is online so a mail can be inserted.. if an account is offline, then only set the LOGIN = 0 and LOGINTMR = 0..

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with it. Use the Event Scheduler to run them once a day.